# Flattening Form fields removes content

Tags: pdf, pdfbox, flatten-pdf

I try to flatten form fields (`PDAcroForm.flatten()`) in a pdf which in the step before got filled from an `.xfdf` file.
The expected result is to have the editable boxes replaced with just the text.

However I from the PDF where the text is filled in the form ([output02.pdf](https://github.com/luckydonald-archive/pdf-stackoverflow-example/raw/master/output02.pdf)) after flattening, all added text is now completely gone, so I get a blank spaces instead of the form values ([output03.pdf](https://github.com/luckydonald-archive/pdf-stackoverflow-example/raw/master/output03.pdf)).

Put a [complete example on github](https://github.com/luckydonald-archive/pdf-stackoverflow-example/tree/02df4c88dcc7cd69ef66c330690f6178545e828d), containing the PDF files (input and the generated output), but here is just the part of the flattening:

```java
// in Main.java, function flatten()

PDDocument pdf_document = PDDocument.load(new File("output02.pdf"));  //from step before, merged & filled pdf files.

List<PDField> the_fields = new ArrayList<PDField>();
for (PDField field: pdf_document.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm().getFieldTree()) {
    the_fields.add(field);
}
System.out.println("Flattening fields: " + Arrays.stream(the_fields.toArray()).map(field -> ((PDField)field).getFullyQualifiedName()).collect(Collectors.joining(", ","[","]")));
pdf_document.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm().flatten(the_fields, true);
pdf_document.save(new File("output03.pdf"));
```

> [image: preview of pdf result]
>   *<sup>The text filled in is gone, too</sup>*

**Edit:**
Created those form elements with `Adobe Acrobat Pro` `10.1.1` on existing PDFs, via the form menu, and simply saved the pdfs as `sample5.pdf` and `test.pdf`.

Comment: One way would be to manually write the text from the form field to the PDF's content stream, with calculating the placement from the existing x,y,w,h box and font size ourself, but that would break with fields having the size set to `Auto`.

Comment: There /V entries (field values) are names but should be strings. I hope that this isn't a PDFBox bug...

Comment: @TilmanHausherr  Created those form elements with `Adobe Acrobat Pro` `10.1.1` on an existing PDF, via the form menu, and simply saved the pdfs as `sample5.pdf` and `test.pdf`.

Comment: To which file's `/V` entries are you refering now?

Comment: In the meantime I ran a part of your code (output01.pdf with test.xfdf) and it worked fine. What PDFBox version did you use? The /V entries are the field values.

Comment: `pdfbox` Version is `2.0.1`, using all the dependencies like specified in the `pom.xml` file.

Comment: Please retry with the current version. Why use 2.0.1 which is several years old?

Comment: You hit a bug that was fixed two years ago: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3596

Comment: I was under the impression to have the latest version. In fact that solved it. Wanna make an answer I can accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug that was fixed since 2.0.5 [two years ago](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3596). Due to that bug, the field values in the xfdf file were assigned as names instead of as strings in the /V entry (for the value) of the field dictionary. Because that, there is nothing to show in the appearance stream of the field. Thus nothing after flattening.

Always use the latest version of PDFBox. I use the [maven versions plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/) in all my projects.

Comment: The maven versions plugin is really a great tool. Thanks!